# how to move div class with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 <div class="full_widget">
    <div class="connect_top clearfix">
    </div>
    <div id="stream_content" class="page_stream_short">
    </div>
    <div class="connections">
    </div>
</div>
```

what i whant to do is  to move connections class in the first place juste after

```
<div class="full_widget">
```

just like this :

```
<div class="full_widget">
    <div class="connections">
    </div>
    <div class="connect_top clearfix">
    </div>
    <div id="stream_content" class="page_stream_short">
    </div>
</div>
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the jquery [prepend](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) function:

```
$('.full_widget').prepend( $('.connections') );
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$(".connections").prependTo(".full_widget");
```

This will always move `.connections` to the inner top of `.full_widget`.

```
$(".connections").insertBefore(".connect_top");
```

If you added in another element to the top, using `insertBefore()` will insure it's displayed right above `.connect_top`, instead of moving it directly to the top.

If you have more than one of those, simply do:

```
$(".connections").prepend(function() {
    var ele = $(this);
    ele.prependTo(ele.parent());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.full_widget').prepend($('.connections'));
```